# Android Bluetooth Low Energy lags TCP communication

Tags: java, android, tcp, delay, bluetooth-lowenergy

Right now im working with a Huawei with android 4.4.2, API 19. Im trying to use the BLE (bluetooth low energy) to discover any other BLE devices nearby at any time, which means that the BLE has to be active all the time. The main problem is that the android 4.2 have some issues with the BLE so it automatically stops discovering devices after 10sec, which means that it has to be stopped and started. The start stop operation causes lag while i have a tcp communication, between the client (phone) and server (PC).

Anyone who knows how to fix the BLE so i dont have to start and stop it every 10sec, or how to make the tcp connection stable? The TCP does not fail as long the BLE are not in use.